# Mail: Unable to load content privately

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, icloud-plus

Recently macOS Mail has been unable to load content privately

[image]

As far as I know, I have not changed any of my settings, but wish to have the privacy option on

[image]

I also have Private Relay turned on in iCloud Preferences

[image]

This has become quite annoying as Little Snitch trips every time a new email comes in

[image]

It may be a coincidence, but around the same time this started happening I switched my ISP to Spectrum.  Nobody else in my household is experiencing this problem; it is happening to just me but on both my laptop and my desktop machine.